# SSIS Package, execute every 13 hours for previous 12 hours of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, dataflow

I have a SSIS Package and I need to schedule it to run at `1:00 AM` and `1:00 PM` every day.

At `1:00 AM` it should pass parameters of the previous day for e.g. 
`15 Nov 2018 12:00 PM` as `@StartDate` & `15 Nov 2018 11:59 PM` as `@EndDate`

At `1:00 PM` it should pass parameters of the current day for e.g. 
`15 Nov 12:00 AM` as `@StartDate` & `15 Nov 11:59 AM`  as `@EndDate`

A stored procedure is called through an OLE DB Source Editor task in Data Flow.

Does anyone have any suggestions that How I could achieve this noting the fact that if the job fails at `1:00 PM`  & it should re-run at `2:00 PM`, it should still pass the same parameters.

Comment: You might want to rethink your StartDate and EndDate windows. `15 Nov 12:00 PM` is one minute AFTER `15 Nov 11:59 AM`. And at `1:00 PM`, if you run for the "current day", you'll be trying to look at 11 hours that haven't happened yet (your EndDate of `15 Nov 11:59 PM` is 10:59 after your run time).

Comment: If "today" is `15 Nov 2018`, then at 1:00am, you should probably set `@StartDate = '14 Nov 2018 12:00 PM'` and `@EndDate = '14 Nov 2018 11:59 PM'`. Then at 1:00pm you would then set `@StartDate = '15 Nov 2018 12:00 AM'` and `@EndDate = '15 Nov 2018 11:59 AM'`

Comment: Yes quite right @digital.aaron. Cheers.

Comment: If you want a job to always pick up from the correct spot then you need t o record this in a table and allow the job to use that table next time it runs. Then you don't have to hard code dates and times anywhere. You schedule it whenever you want and however frequently you want, and it just works.

Comment: Exactly @Nick.McDermaid, good point, if you want to post this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to pass the date parameters to OLEDB task.

1. Have start date & end date parameters in (I suppose you must be having).
2. Assign the dates values to both parameters using SQL task.
3. Pass these parameters to OLDEB stored procedure to data flow task.

For scheduling:

Create two different jobs for each run, one for 1 AM & another for 2 AM of the job.

For second job run, implement the following steps.

1. Create a table which log the job execution status with date and time. That table has insertion after each run of the job.
2. When second job schedule execute first check log table in first step and check the last run status of the job.
3. If it was successful exit else go to next step.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for responding, but it doesn't really make sense and needs more detail. The jobs are 1am, and 1pm, not 1am and 2am.